# Reduce the particle size (Blender 3.3 Mantaflow fluid simulation)

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm working on a smaller project and I need to do a fluid simulation. I'm working on a centimeter scale. The particle size is too huge and the simulation is broken (the fluid disappears). I have set the Resolution Divisions to 100 and Time scale to 0.2. The Particle Radius is 0.0001. I tried to play with this value, but it didn't do anything.

Look at the screenshot.

[image: Settings]

[image: Huge simulation particles]

[image: Before simulation]

Comment: " I'm working on a centimeter scale. " -> i think, that is the problem. Scale everything up, increase resolution and it will be better. If not, pls provide blend file. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Particle display size is not in the **Physics** tab but in the **Particle** tab > **Viewport Display > Size**.

(I've been looking for this for years and I found it today. It brings tears to my eyes.)